# Mark checkbox as checked if user has a role

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve options from a database to a checkbox. If the user has the role, it has to be checked by default. Otherwise show as unchecked.
Currently if the users has at least one role, all the checkboxes are marked as checked.

```
<?php
// Display user information on table
$query = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email FROM users ORDER BY user_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$records_roles = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT role_name FROM roles");
$roles = array();
$count = 0;

while ($course_roles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records_roles)){
    $roles []= $course_roles['role_name'];
    $count++;
}

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "
              <tr>
               <td "?> style="display:none" <?php echo">".$row['user_id']."</td>
               <td>".$row['first_name']."</td>
               <td>".$row['last_name']."</td>
               <td>".$row['email']."</td>
               <td>
                    <form method='post'>
                        Select user roles<br/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value=".$row["user_id"].">
               ";

                for ($a = 1; $a <= $count ; $a++){
                    $new_sql = "SELECT role_id from users_roles, users WHERE users_roles.user_id = '".$row["user_id"]."' GROUP BY users_roles.user_id";
                    //_log('select if checked or not: '.$new_sql);
                    $checked_or_not = mysqli_query($connect, $new_sql);
                    //print_r($checked_or_not);
                    if ($checked_or_not->num_rows != 0){
                        echo "<input type='checkbox' checked name='techno[]' value='$a' />" .$roles[($a-1)]. "<br>";
                    }

                    else if ($checked_or_not->num_rows == 0){
                        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='techno[]' value='$a' />" .$roles[($a-1)]. "<br>";
                    }

//                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='techno[]' value='$a' />" .$roles[($a-1)]. "<br>";
                }
                echo "
                    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='checkSubmit' >Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                ";

                echo"
               </tr>
                ";
            }
            ?>
```

user_roles table:
[image: user_roles table]

Current Output: Last User does not have any roles assigned and all the checkboxes show as unchecked. First three users have only 1 role each one and all the checkboxes show as checked.

Comment: " if the user has the same role" what do you mean by this? The same role as opposed to what exactly?

Comment: I don't understand the question either.

Comment: Are you saying that users with a `user_id` of '1', '2' and '3' all have a `role_id` value of one, so three checked checkboxes should appear?

Comment: user_id of '1', '2' and '3' all have a role_id value of 1. Role 1 = 'Admin'. Only Admin checkbox should be checked for users of user_id '1', '2' and '3'

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It's worth noting these gigantic screenshots add nothing of value to the question and could be omitted.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role query is just checking if user has any role so it will return always true (if user has at least 1 role) or always false (if user has no role).

Instead

```
$new_sql = "SELECT role_id from users_roles, users WHERE users_roles.user_id = '".$row["user_id"]."' GROUP BY users_roles.user_id";
```

You have to add a filter by `role_id`.

```
$new_sql = "SELECT role_id from users_roles, users WHERE users_roles.user_id = '".$row["user_id"]."' AND users_roles.role_id = '" . $a . "' GROUP BY users_roles.user_id";
```

**Note: As sugested in the comments you should use parameterized queries to protect against sql injection attacks. Also you should escape variables before echoing to protect against cross-site scripting (xss) attacks.**

Above change should fix your problem but I have some suggestions. Check below.

**Suggestion 1:**
You are assuming that `role_id` is the same as `$count` index.
If you don't have a sequential id in roles table that starts with 1 or by any chance the result order is changed then code will break.

`$roles` array needs to track role ID. Subsequent code need to change accordingly.

Assuming column `id` in roles table:

```
$records_roles = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, role_name FROM roles");
$roles = array();
$count = 0;

while ($course_roles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records_roles)){
    // Keep track of roles ID
    $roles[] = [
        'id' => $course_roles['id'],
        'name' => $course_roles['role_name'],
    ];
    
    $count++;
}
```

**Suggestion 2:**
You are executing a database query to check for each role individually. This affects code performance.

Get all roles of the user in 1 query and then compare role id in the array.

Complete code with 2 suggestions will look like this

```
<?php
// Display user information on table
$query = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email FROM users ORDER BY user_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$records_roles = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, role_name FROM roles");
$roles = array();

while ($course_roles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records_roles)){
    // Keep track of roles ID
    $roles[] = [
        'id' => $course_roles['id'],
        'name' => $course_roles['role_name'],
    ];
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td style='display:none'>".$row['user_id']."</td>
    <td>".$row['first_name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['last_name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['email']."</td>
    <td>
    <form method='post'>
    Select user roles<br/>
    <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value=".$row["user_id"].">
    ";

    // Get all user roles
    $new_sql = "SELECT role_id FROM users_roles WHERE user_id = '".$row["user_id"]."' GROUP BY user_id";
    $user_roles_result = mysqli_query($connect, $new_sql);
    $user_roles = [];
    while ($row_user_roles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_roles_result)){
        // Put user roles in array
        $user_roles[] = $row_user_roles['role_id'];
    }
    
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($role['id'], $user_roles)) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' checked name='techno[]' value='{$role['id']}' />" .$role['name']. "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='techno[]' value='{$role['id']}' />" .$role['name']. "<br>";
        }
    }

    echo "
    <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='checkSubmit' >Submit</button>
    </form>
    </td>
    ";
    
    echo "
    </tr>
    ";
}
```